# How can I save a route of type Uri: content, in a flat file and how do I recover it of type Uri:content to assign it to an imageview

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following code to save two text strings in a flat file, one of type string and another of type Uri that I convert to String until here it is saved correctly separated by a divider.

I show the code.

```
    private fun saveToFile(){
       try {
                val archivo = OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("MisComidas.txt", MODE_APPEND))
                val text= binding.etComida.text.toString()+"#"+imgUri.toString()+"\n"

                archivo.write(text)
                archivo.flush()
                archivo.close()
        } catch (_: IOException) {
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Comida-->${dataSet.size} Guardada Correctamente" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

I want to be able to obtain the string str1 already converted to uri and display the image that comes from the image gallery when loading a list in a recyclerview.

In this other method I try to recover the data from the flat file and convert the image path to Uri again to assign it to the imageview

```
    private fun readFile(){
        if (fileList().contains("MisComidas.txt")) {
            try {
                var texto = ""
                val archivo = InputStreamReader(openFileInput("MisComidas.txt"))
                val br = BufferedReader(archivo)
                var linea = br.readLine()
                while (linea != null) {

                    val pos1 = linea.indexOf("#")
                    val str = linea.substring(0, pos1)
                    val str1 = (linea.substring(pos1+1)).toUri()

                    dataSet.add(ComidaData(str,str1))
                    texto = texto + linea + "\n"
                    linea = br.readLine()
                }
                br.close()
                archivo.close()
            } catch (_: IOException) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not working in your current approach ? Do you get an error message/log ? Or is it that the image just do not show up ?

Comment: The application bursts, I run it in debug mode and just when I want to show the item in the recyclerview it bursts, I think that the uri does not take it as such and that is why it does not assign it to the imageview.

Comment: As you can see in the data recovery method of the flat file, I add it to a mutable array called data set, there is supposed to be a string data type and another uri content type, which is the address of the image, to then load the recyclerview.